# Detect collision for particles and Wind effect

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, collision-detection, particles

I'm looking to achieve [this effect.](https://youtu.be/j1052qNC9II?t=23s)

I thought about making WIND PARTICLES and then when the player collides with it, force will be applied. But how can I check if the player collided with the WIND PARTICLES?

If you have other suggestions about how this effect can be achieved I will be more than thankful!

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to do the collision test with particles,  You want to use the `SKFieldNode` to achieve this effect.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skfieldnode

I am not sure which one to use for the wind effect, but at least it will get you started on the right direction, but basically what it does is set up a "force field"  and the node hits this force field, some kind of physics get applied to it.

Comment: Thanks! Is the skfieldnode visible? or should i add it to an sknode?

Comment: SKFieldNode is invisible You can add it to either the node or the scene